# Databricks: save to DWH (Synapse) in consistent way

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

Databricks has a [great Synapse connector](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html#usage-batch-1) that take a burden of bulk uploading. Under the hood, the connector is creating a temporary folder at your Blob Storage, and use Polybase external tables to load to Synapse very quickly.

Currently I have ETL doing bulk load to Synapse on daily basis (writting or overwritting single date partition).

*Is there any option to ensure consistency while loading from Databricks to Synapse?*

I mean [partition switching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-best-practices-transactions#optimizing-with-partition-switching) or at least any transactional support. Shall I write a custom database cleansing logic for cases when Databricks job fall in the middle, so I have removed previous data and written only the half of dataset?

### UPD

The official doc says "use the Data Source API". *Is there any reasons of not loading data into main table except the risk to make updated partition inconsistent?*

> Apply some transformations to the data, then use the Data Source
>   API to write the data back to another table in Azure Synapse.

```
df.write   
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")   
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>")  
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")  
  .option("dbTable", "my_table_in_dw_copy")   
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://...")
  .save()
```